# Regex to see if ] appears before [ (x before y), but not straight after

Tags: regex, markdown

*I hate asking regex questions.*

### Subject

Here’s an example of my subject:

```
You should get yourself some free coconut water! It’s lovely! Because
[coconut water](/buy/) is so affordable, you should totally get some. Get
some [free coconut water today](/buy/)!
```

### Task

I want to replace `coconut water` with a link: `[coconut water](/buy/)`. However, some links have been added to the text already (using different versions), I want to add links where they are missing.

### Summary

In human speak, here’s what I’m trying to do:

- Replace the phrase `coconut water` with `[coconut water](/buy/)`
- Do not replace if it’s already a link (`[coconut water](/buy/)`)
- Do not replace if it’s already in a link (`[free coconut water!](/buy/)`)

### Attempts

The first problem, where it may already be a link, can be avoided using this regex:

```
(?<!\[)coconut water(?!\])
```

It works for two our of the three.

- ✅ Matches `coconut water`
- ✅ Ignores `[coconut water](/buy/)`
- ❌ Matches `[free coconut water today](/buy/)`

Just for clarity, the last one would turn `[free coconut water today](/buy/)` into `[free [coconut water](/buy/) today](/buy/)`.

### Next

The common reoccurance, because it’s Markdown, is that `]` will always appear at some point after if it’s already a link. So what I can’t figure out is how to say to that to regex:

*Match the phrase but only if `[` appears before `]` afterwards*

When I’ve searched around Stack Overflow and search engines the most common response is to do with it directly after or before the word, but I want it to be flexible so that it would ignore:

- `[free coconut water today](/buy/)`
- `[try some coconut water](/buy/)`
- `[lovely coconut water for sale](/buy/)`

### Context

I’m using PCRE regex in PHP. There is more than one phrase to scan for, so it’s actually replace `x` with `[x](y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find and skip the links and replace the matches in all other contexts:

```
\[[^][]*]\(\/buy\/\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\bcoconut water\b
```

Replace with `[$0](/buy/)`. If there can be any word instead of `buy`, use `[^\/]+` or `\w+`.

I added word boundaries around `coconut water` to only match the phrase as a whole word.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/imgZKC/2)

**Details**

- `\[[^][]*]\(\/buy\/\)` - `[`, then any 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`, then a `](/buy/)`  text
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - PCRE verbs discarding the current match attempt and resuming the search for the next match from the current position
- `|` - or
- `\bcoconut water\b` - a whole word match for a `coconut water` phrase.

Comment: Wow! Never heard of `SKIP` or `FAIL`, that’s fantastic. Fortunatly using `preg_replace` with a list of pre-defined replacements, so the replacement is quite easy.

Comment: Pro skills! TIL about `SKIP` and `FAIL`. Thanks ;)

Comment: I’ve updated it to `\[[^][]*]\(\/[\w-]+\/?\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\bcoconut water\b` to allow for `-` in URLs and non-trailing slashes.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Yes, feel free to adjust the pattern, the `(/buy/)` part is hardcoded in your question and no additional requirements for this part pattern are provided, so it is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead to exclude matches that are followed by any characters and a `]` in your group:

`(?<!\[)coconut water(?!.*\])(?!\])`

https://regex101.com/r/kbquGp/1

> Matches ***coconut water*** and ***coconut water*** again 
>   Ignores [coconut water](/buy/) 
>  ignores [free coconut water
>   today](/buy/) and matches ***coconut water***  
>  ignores [coconut
>   water yay](/buy/) and matches ***coconut water*** water ftw